# Implementing an ajax call within another ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to replace the view with another view returned by a method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Info(int personid) 
        {
             ...
             return View("...", ViewModel)
        }
```

The SearchCandidates method does the search. Then according to what action we can perform on the returned candidates (refund or info). The call to the respective method is done correctly. The refund part works, we don't need to return anything special. But for the info method, we return a view and it's not displayed. I have checked and the response on the browser is correct and is exactly what I need to use for UI purposes.

I get on console.log(data) an object but for the response (the actual returned view) I receive "undefined" instead of the View.

````
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ToDoHome/SearchCandidates',
                    data: {
                        submit: "searchCandidates",
                        FirstnameStartsWith: $("#FirstNameStartsWith").val(),
                        LastnameStartsWith: $("#LastNameStartsWith").val(),
                        StartDate: $("#StartDate").val(),
                        EndDate: $("#EndDate").val(),
                        TestcenterPlaceFilter: $("#TestcenterPlaceIdFilter").val(),
                        TestcenterIdFilter: $("#TestcenterIdFilter").val(),
                        HasRemarks: $("#HasRemarks").val(),
                        HasCertification: $("#HasCertification").val()
                    },
                    success: function (data, response) {
                        $(`#ResultTable`).replaceWith(data).promise().done(
                            $('.refund').on('click', function () {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'post',
                                    url: '/ToDoHome/DoRefund',
                                    data: {
                                        personid: this.id
                                    },
                                    success: function () {console.log("successRefund")
                                    }
                                });
                            }),
                            $('.info').on('click', function (data,response) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    async: false,
                                    type: 'get',
                                    url: '/ToDoHome/Info',
                                    data: {
                                        personid: this.id
                                    },
                                    success: function () {
                                        const convertStringToHTML = htmlString => {
                                            const parser = new DOMParser();
                                            const html = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');

                                            return html.body;
                                        }
                                        console.log(convertStringToHTML(data));
                                        console.log(convertStringToHTML(response));
                                        $('#SearchCandidateInfos').replaceWith(response);
                                    }
                                });
                            })
                        );
                        var newUrlParameters = window.location.pathname
                            + "?FirstNameStartsWith=" + $("#FirstNameStartsWith").val()
                            + "&LastNameStartsWith=" + $("#LastNameStartsWith").val()
                            + "&StartDate=" + $("#StartDate").val()
                            + "&EndDate=" + $("#EndDate").val()
                            + "&TestcenterPlaceIdFilter=" + $("#TestcenterPlaceIdFilter").val()
                            + "&TestcenterIdFilter=" + $("#TestcenterIdFilter").val()
                            + "&HasRemarks=" + $("#HasRemarks").val()
                            + "&HasCertification=" + $("#HasCertification").val();
                        window.history.pushState('', '', newUrlParameters);
                    }
                });
            };```
````

Comment: `$('.info').on('click', function (data,response) {…}`. The click method doesn’t accept a data or a response param.  `data` should come from the success function parameter, eg `success: function(data) { … }`.